# Adding text that appears and disappears after a certain time, at specific positions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add text above the first circle that says "Stage 1" for 1 to 1.5s, then disappears and then another text "Stage 2" appears above the final position of the circle, that then disappears after 1 to 1.5s as well.

Right now, I have the text working, but not in the correct position and it does not disappear as well. Any help will be massively appreciated! Thanks :)

Code:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<title>D3 Starter Fun Time!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/simple-style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon/favicon.ico">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
   </head>

<body>

    <clipPath id ="myClip">
    <div id="chartDiv"></div>
</clipPath>
    <div id="otherDiv"></div>
    <button id="next">Play Animation</button>
    <div id="changeText"></div>
     <script>
var duration = 4000;
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                     .attr("width", 800)
                                     .attr("height", 400);

 //Draw the Circle
 var circle = svgContainer.append("circle")
                          .attr("cx", 90)
                          .attr("cy", 90)
                          .attr("fill","black")
                         .attr("r", 80);

                         var text = ["Stage 1", "Stage 2"];
                         var counter = 0;
                         var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
                         //var inst = setInterval(change, 1000);
                         elem.innerHTML = text[0];
                         function change(flag)
                         {
                             elem.innerHTML = text[1];
                         }


document.getElementById("next").onclick = function() {linearReductionMed(600, 20)};

function linearReductionMed(x, r){
    circle.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("cx", x)
    .attr("r", r)
    setTimeout(function(){ change(); }, duration);
}

function linearReductionSlow(x, r){
    circle.transition()
    .duration(duration*2)
    .attr("cx", x)
    .attr("r", r)
        setTimeout(function(){ change(); }, duration*2);
}


function linearReductionFast(x, r){
    circle.transition()
    .duration(duration/2)
    .attr("cx", x)
    .attr("r", r)
          setTimeout(function(){ change(); }, duration/2);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

To make the text disappear you could use `elem.innerHTML = ""`. For instance:

```
function show() {
   elem.innerHTML = text;
   setTimeout(hide, 1000);
}

function hide() {
   elem.innerHTML = '';
}
```

To change the text position add some styling to `<div id="changeText">` on the css, for instance (change according to what you need):

```
div#changeText {
   float: left;
   left: 300px;
   top: 100px; 
}
```